# save custom term - hook create_term doesn't work

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

i'm trying to save a custom term with my own informations.

i tried the hooks:
- create_term
- created_term
- create_{my_taxonomy}

but nothing seems to work.

when I save the term, it's only getting saved with the default wordpress informations.
When I then edit the term, the hook
- edit_term
works finde!

actually I have no idea, why the create_term is not fired.
is there anything else to do or any other hook.
or is it a problem, that wordpress saves the term by ajax?

here a code snipped of how i use the hook

```
if ( ! defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class my_term_class {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'create_term', array( $this, 'save_my_fields' ), 10, 3 ); 
        add_action( 'edit_term', array( $this, 'save_my_fields' ), 10, 3 );
        //...
    }

    public function save_my_fields( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '' ) {
        write_log("this log is only written by edit_term!");
        //...
    }
}
new my_term_class();
```

---

Edit:
I created a brand new taxonomie to my post type. but still the same problem.

here the Code I create the taxonomie:

```
        register_taxonomy("cstesttaxonomy", 
        array('myposttype'),
        array(
            "label"             => _n('Testtaxonomie', 'Testtaxonomies', 2, 'cs-poedit'),
            'public'            => false,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          => _n('Testtaxonomie', 'Testtaxonomies', 2, 'cs-poedit'),
                'sigular_name'  => _n('Testtaxonomie', 'Testtaxonomies', 1, 'cs-poedit'),
                'menu_name'     => _n('Testtaxonomie', 'Testtaxonomies', 1, 'cs-poedit'),
                'edit_item'     => __('Edit testtax', 'cs-poedit'),
                'view_item'     => __('View testtax', 'cs-poedit'),
                'update_item'   => __('Update testtax', 'cs-poedit'),
                'add_new_item'  => __('Add new testtax', 'cs-poedit'),
                //                     'new_item_name' => 'Optionsbezeichnung',
                'popular_items' => NULL,
            ),
            "hierarchical"      => false,
            "singular_label"    => _n('Testtaxonomie', 'Testtaxonomies', 1, 'cs-poedit'),
            'rewrite'           => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,

            'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
        )
    );
```

than I add the administration view for this taxonomie to my admin menu:

```
private function initAdminHooks() {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'initAdminMenu'));
}

public function initAdminMenu() {
    add_menu_page('MyMenu', 'MyMenu', 'edit_posts', 'cs_mymenu', 'show', plugins_url('myplugin/myicon_16x16.ico'), 3);
    //...
    add_submenu_page('cs_mymenu', _n('TestTax', 'TestTax', 2, 'cs-poedit'),_n('TestTax', 'TestTaxes', 2, 'cs-poedit'), 'manage_options', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=cstesttaxonomy&post_type=myposttype', false);
}
```

and then in the administration view I want to add a new taxonomie and when the taxonomie is beeing saved, i want to write a log (if that works, i want to add own fields to the taxonomie and save custom values to a custom database table)

and my class to do that and handle the save method is:

```
if ( ! defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class RS_IB_MyTest {

public function mytest1( $term_id = 0, $tt_id ='') {
    write_log("Stest1");
}
public function mytest2( $term_id, $tt_id ='',$asd = '' ) {
    write_log("Stest2");
}        

public function __construct() {
    write_log("construct");
    add_action( 'create_cstesttaxonomy', array($this, 'mytest1'), 10, 2 );        

    add_action( 'edit_term', array( $this, 'mytest2' ), 10, 3 );
}
}
new RS_IB_MyTest();
```

but still, only the method from the "edit_term" hook is fired correctly.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue with your code. Can you post the real code you are using? What are you trying do exactly?

Comment: I updatet my post. but even with a new taxonomy i'm getting the same problem

Comment: Againg, your code works perfectly here. Can you add the code you are using to register the custom taxonomy?

Comment: I have added the code for register the taxonomy. see the first code block of my edit --> register_taxonomy("cstesttaxonomy", .....

or have I missunderstand your question?

Comment: I see your `register_taxonomy()` but not the hook where you execute it. Are you using `init` action to register the taxonomy?

Comment: I found out, that the register_taxonomy() is not the problem. when I put "add_action( 'create_term', 'my_create', 10, 3 );" directly in the first lines of my initial plugin-file, it works! I try to find out why it not works in my included file

Answer (score 1):

I found my failure...
a few months ago I added the following line to my code:

```
if(!(defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)) {
    include_once 'mytestfile.php';
}
```

in this file, I add my action for creating a term...
with this line, i wanted to prevent to load some files that I doesn't need when I'm using AJAX...
but wordpress is using AJAX for create a new term..

now I removed this if-statement and everything works well...

sorry that I stolen your time for this stupid failure..
but maybe someone has the same problem and is happy about my post :-D